# need for schengen visa if i have US visa

Tags: usa

I am travelling to Chicago from saudi via FRANKFURT AND PARIS. Do I need a schengen visa if I have a valid visa for USA? I am an Indian national.

Comment: Yes.  Your valid US visa exempts you from the requirement to hold an *airport transit visa* for trips where you don't pass through Schengen border controls.  But for this trip, you need to fly from Frankfurt to Paris, which means that you need to enter the Schengen zone.  You therefore require a normal Schengen short-stay visa; having a US visa does not change that.